# .js and endless spinner

Tags: javascript, loading

An endless spinner appears on all pages of the site: www.civicmusicmilwaukee.org. After disarming javascript in Chrome the endless spinner disappears so I'm assuming that's the issue. The website appeared fine for the last 4 months, then all of a sudden the endless spinner...

Comment: Looks like it is trying to start a fancybox on pageload. Fancybox is javascript plugin. Specifically, the id is "fancybox-loading"

Answer (score 2):

Console shows:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: thickboxL10n

I'm betting that error prevents the fancybox to go away. Simple error to fix I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

Check your Developer Tools, you will see the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: thickboxL10n is not defined ".  It is as @le_garry says, the FancyBox is hosed.

EDIT:

I dug a little deeper.  It looks like the stylesheet for the fancybox is being loaded from a different domain.  If you look at the code, you'll see that the CSS for FancyBox is being loaded from here: `http://cdn1.editmysite.com/editor/libraries/fancybox/fancybox.css?1349896606`  It is likely that since this domain is called "EditMySite" that someone has, in fact, edited their site to make the fancybox loading thing now Visible by default.

Check out the [Google Cache of this site](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:6xHQ_hpECe0J%3awww.civicmusicmilwaukee.org/%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) from October 6, 2012.

You will find that there are some differences between the current site and the old site.  Specifically, the stylesheets included:

Current:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://cdn1.editmysite.com/editor/libraries/fancybox/fancybox.css?1349896606'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://cdn1.editmysite.com/editor/images/common/common-v2.css?buildTime=1349896606' type='text/css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/files/main_style.css?1350355889' title='wsite-theme-css' />
```

Google Cache:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://cdn1.editmysite.com/editor/images/common/common-v2.css?buildTime=1345058381' type='text/css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/files/main_style.css?1345140958' title='wsite-theme-css' />
```

That whole `fancybox.css` stylesheet wasn't even there a couple weeks ago.  All signs point to it being the culprit.  Check out line 82 on `fancybox.css`  that's the style for the `#fancybox-loading` element.  If you are able to, modify that element to include a `display:none;` in it, then that loading thing will be gone by default.  You'll want to make sure that this doesn't actually impact the fancyboxes that you have on your site.

As I and @dda have both said, there is also something going on with the implementation of the fancybox as well, But this should get you off to a good start.

Comment: Very helpful- I wasn't using fancybox as far as I know. I assume deleting the script call reference it would solve the problem so now need to figure out how to access this code snippet in weebly.

Comment: Cool I deleted the custom font avenir.js (which called the fancybox madness) and it seems to have solved itself. Really bizarre since it was working fine for 6 months and then broke. Anyway thanks for the comments they are tremendously helpful!